# How Can i Check Full text search catalog available in SQL with SCRIPT?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search, catalog, full-text-catalog

How Can i Check Full text search catalog available in SQL with SCRIPT?

Answer (score 4):

You can list the currently configured catalogs with the sql below:

```
select * from sys.fulltext_catalogs
```

[See Full-Text Search Catalog Views at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280702.aspx)

Comment: Thank You....Neysor.
But I want to Check Is Fulltext Catalog available or not in SQL Server 2005...

Comment: oh, sorry:  
        select FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')